# Store URL with wildcards in MySQL and return matches

Tags: php, mysql, regex, routes, wildcard

I'm writing a PHP router, which lookups page's id in database with such query

```
SELECT `id` FROM `pages` WHERE '/about/test' REGEXP `url` ORDER BY `url`
```

from such table

```
id  type_id url             name    lookup  
1   0       /about/[^/]*    NULL    NULL
2   1       /about/company  NULL    NULL
```

So it gets id `2` on `'/about/company'` and id `1` on `/about/whatever` on first row of result

I'm looking for the best way to retrieve the wildcard values from MySQL, e.g. get ID of `'/about/[^/]+'` entry and `'test'` as second argument when passing `'/about/test'`; and get only ID when passing `'/about/company'`

Simply, i want to get variadic number of columns, where first column return ID and others - wildcard values in right order

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I, for one, do not follow the explanation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added table sample and more clear question

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have a flag that specifies if something is a wildcard pattern or a simple comparison.

If you want all matches, you can do:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `pages`
WHERE '/about/test' REGEXP `url` AND url_has_wildcard = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT `id`
FROM `pages`
WHERE '/about/test' REGEXP `url` AND url_has_wildcard = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM pages
                  WHERE '/about/test' REGEXP `url` AND url_has_wildcard = 0
                 );
```

You can define such a flag using -- what else -- a regular expression.  Say, something like this:

```
WHERE '/about/test' REGEXP `url` AND
      (url REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9/]*$') -- or whatever the valid characters are
```

If you want only one row returned, you can do:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `pages`
WHERE '/about/test' REGEXP `url` 
ORDER BY (url REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9/]*$') DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This way I could determine if URL was wildcarded or not, but i want also to get the substituted strings for each wildcard.